# Is it possible to install an earlier version of Skype on Windows 8?

Tags: windows, skype

Windows 8 skype is terrible.  They've removed many buttons, most of the preferences, and have in general made it impossibly oversimplified and difficult to use.

Old Skype was fine when I had windows 7.  Is there any way to get it back on Windows 8?

Answer (score 1):

Install the [desktop version of Skype.](https://support.skype.com/en/faq/FA12162/how-do-i-get-the-desktop-version-of-skype-windows-8-or-above)

> To start using Skype for Windows desktop:
>
> - Download the latest version of Skype for Windows desktop.
> - The download bar appears at the bottom of your internet browser. Tap or click Save.
> - After the download ends, tap or click Run.
> - When prompted, select Yes to start installing Skype.
> - Windows 8 switches to the desktop and Skype opens.
> - Sign in and start speaking to your friends.